# How can I rearrange the order of elements inside of a flexbox according to the screen size?

Tags: html, css

I am working with a designer that gave me the following style. I don't know how I would be able to replicate this in plain CSS without having to rearrange the objects manually.

Here is a text visualization of what I want to achieve.

> ###blank space##### Default, element 1, element 3, element 5

> ###blank space##### element 2, element 4, element 6

However, when the screen size is reduced:

> Default option

> element 1

> element 2

> element 3

> element 4

> element 5

> element 6

Basically, when the screen is large enough, all the odds index on the top row and all the even index on the bottom. However, when the screen isn't large enough, he wants the element in a column with the elements in the right order. Take note that on the top row there is a default option that is always on top. (either first in first row or top of the vertical column)

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: @StefanAvramovic it doesn't answer how I'm supposed to place them initially.

Comment: have you tried -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-flow` or rather `flex-direction` to set the items either in a column or a row. If you want to change the position of a single item you can use the property `order` on it.
Learn more about ordering flex items [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. However, since I will have 2 rows, how can I place one on the top row and one on the bottom row. I am quite good with flex, but this part I really don't understand...

Comment: When you're working with multiple rows or columns i would always suggest using grid instead of flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the css `order` property.

You put the elements in the right order for the mobile view. When the window gets big enough, you change the order of the individual elements with a media query.

And using pseudo class `:nth-child()` you can move even or odd boxes on the top row

```css
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}


.container > div {
  background: green;
  margin: .5rem;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .container > div {
    width: calc(50% - 1rem);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .container > div:nth-child(even) {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1">1</div>
  <div class="box-2">2</div>
  <div class="box-3">3</div>
  <div class="box-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to achieve what you did using spans and I can't get them to break to a new line. I don't know how many there will be so I don't want to have to add the line break manually.

Comment: that happens because spans are online elements. Try setting display: block; for the spans and it should work

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code: https://codepen.io/asteroidsnowsuit/pen/YzwvxKB

Comment: you are missing essential parts from the code I posted in my answer. The media queries is necessary, and everything else I wrote